# Unable to send messages back to the client from the server using Oak websocket middleware in Deno

Tags: websocket, deno, oak

When using the below code, the `echo2` message is never received by the client. The first message, `echo1` -- which is prior to the await, is received by the client. If I remove the `await`, both messages are received by the client.

I know the `await` is somehow interrupting the websocket. What am I missing?

Server Code:

```
import {
  Application,
  Router
} from "https://deno.land/x/oak@v12.1.0/mod.ts";

const app = new Application();
const router = new Router();

async function pause(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

router.get("/ws", (ctx) => {
  console.log("ws connected");
  if (!ctx.isUpgradable) {
    ctx.throw(501);
  }
  const ws = ctx.upgrade();

  ws.onopen = () => {
    ws.send(JSON.stringify({ intent: "init", id: "test" }));
  };

  ws.addEventListener("message", async (ev) => {
    const d = JSON.parse(ev.data);
    console.log("got message", d);
    switch (d.intent) {
      case "echo": {
        ws.send(JSON.stringify({ intent: "echo1", data: { empty: true } }));
        await pause(1000);
        ws.send(JSON.stringify({ intent: "echo2", data: { empty: true } }));
        break;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

EDIT: I was using a simple WS client chrome extension to test the websocket, not writing explicit code.

Comment: This code is working as expected for me when I add the router to the app and listen on some port. How does your client look like?

Comment: **You describe a problem with client code, but don't show any client code.** Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76601237/edit) the question to include a [mre] (see [ask]). As far as the server code shown: be sure to use an up-to-date version of [oak](https://deno.land/x/oak) (`12.1.0` is outdated). The `app` needs to `use` the router and needs to be started by using its `listen` method. See this [basic usage example](https://deno.land/x/oak@v12.5.0#basic-usage) in the docs for reference.

Comment: [Here's an example in the TypeScript playground](https://tsplay.dev/wgavlm) showing a test that uses a slightly modified version of your server code and demonstrates that it works — note that you'll see lots of compiler diagnostic errors because the playground doesn't support Deno syntax or multiple files, but you can copy + paste the contents into local modules and reproduce what's there. Does that address your question? If so, i can write it up as an answer — if not, what am I missing? Either way, please edit the question to clarify according to the information in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue resolved itself when I upgraded from deno `1.32.x` to `1.34.3`.